# Flutter - Could not find a command named "-"

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I'm new to flutter, when I created a new project of flutter and run it, this appears :

```
Using hardware rendering with device AOSP on IA Emulator. If you notice graphics artifacts,
consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Could not find a command named "-".

Usage: dart [<vm-flags>] <command|dart-file> [<arguments>]

Global options:
-h, --help                 Print this usage information.
-v, --verbose              Show additional command output.
    --version              Print the Dart SDK version.
    --enable-analytics     Enable anonymous analytics.
    --disable-analytics    Disable anonymous analytics.

Available commands:
  analyze   Analyze the project's Dart code.
  compile   Compile Dart to various formats.
  create    Create a new project.
  fix       Apply automated fixes to Dart source code.
  format    Idiomatically format Dart source code.
  migrate   Perform a null safety migration on a project or package.
  pub       Work with packages.
  run       Run a Dart program.
  test      Run tests in this package.

Run "dart help <command>" for more information about a command.
See https://dart.dev/tools/dart-tool for detailed documentation.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        510ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 64
```

I'm stuck with this problem, how to solve this?

Comment: i have no issues found in flutter doctor -v

Comment: What command are you entering?

Comment: @ScottGodfrey this issue appears when I tried to "flutter run" in cmd or vscode

Comment: try a flutter clean, then flutter run

Comment: @ScottGodfrey still same

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem. I run this project in my D: directory while my flutter and android SDK was installed in C: directory. So, when I tried to create flutter project in C:, it worked. But, I still can't configure why this problem happened.

Answer (score 0):

@Papskipapap may I ask, if running your project on D: also inculded some path name which contained a "-" (dash) in it? As a rule of thumb: Keep pathnames easy, i.e. without blanks or special characters other than "_" (underscore), many tools just can not handle those...